# Sidebar height stretch with the content height CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

How would i make the sidebar div stretch the same height as the content.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

Here is my example code with other elements:

http://tinkerbin.com/tkp2FZLZ

it has a content DIV in the Middle and 4 divs that makes border which is a different color.

Comment: You've got a markup mistake, change `<div="id="content">` to `<div id="content">`

Comment: Here's my fiddle showing how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/magickirbyz/Lyxwumxv/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get your desired results through `display:table-cell;`

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>

<div id="content">content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
display:table-cell;
width:100px;
background:red;

}
#content {
display:table-cell;
width:100px;
background:yellow;
height:200px;
}
```

i think you are looking like this ;- 
http://tinkerbin.com/yqyX3mXg

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-cell` on both column.

That will (visually! and visually only. It's CSS) make them behave the same way as `th/td` cells. You can add `table-layout: fixed; display: table` on parent and some width on one or both columns to use the *other* table algorithm, the one that doesn't try to adapt to content but try to respect the widths YOU want.

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">typo in your code, an =" was removed</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar, #content {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

EDIT: compatible with IE8+
You'll have to use inline-block for IE6/IE7 ... that they don't understand (ha!). `display: inline; zoom: 1` is the alternative for them, or you can also float these columns and use a technique named *faux-column* (tl;dr the background is on the parent and it's a visual fake, it appears to be on each column but it isn't)
EDIT2: `vertical-align: top` is also often required for such layout columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does this method fully support older versions of IE?

Comment: I edited my answer with support for IE6/7 (inline-block and faux-columns, depends if you want the exact same result on IE6 and modern browsers and if fixed widths is an option or not. IMHO having 2 columns but some bugginess with backgrounds is enough with IE7-. The text is at the same place and that's the important part.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     #sidebar { position: relative; }
     #content { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; }

     <div id="sidebar">
     <div id="content">
     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the same height for them, you could possibly even give them a float.
By the way you have a bug in your html, write it like so:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>​
```

And the css:

```
#sidebar{
width: 40px;
height:350px;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#content{
width: 165px;
height:350px;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

​
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WpxCP/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The content is a dynamic where content will chop and change, so the height of the content can stretch constantly.