# html css 2 column layout, both columns same height automatically?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a two column layout set up, and I want to have both columns automatically stretch to fill parent div of the two columns, The reason being that the left column has a background and border to it, and i want it to take up the entire side of the page so it won't look messy and such. I use inline-block to align the two columns, not float or anything (I can't use overflow:hidden because it messes up some of my features that may go out of the div, ex: dropdown menus)  So I need to find a simple way to do this, using this method.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sFBGX/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **CSS** table layout (not HTML table layout, that would be poor semantics):

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 944px;
    font-size: 0.75em;

}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.container .left
{
    width: 236px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.container .right
{
    width: 708px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col left">Left</div>
    <div class="col right">Right
    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>Hey
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Compatibility is IE8+ and fallback for IE6/7 if needed is exactly the same as for `inline-block`

Longer explanations in previous answers: **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359407/sidebar-height-stretch-with-the-content-height-css/11359442#11359442)** and **[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019386/html-css-how-to-create-four-equal-size-tabs-that-fill-100-width/12019783#12019783)** with also the good old method of *faux-columns* (your design must be thought with this technique in mind)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good way of doing it, and I just finished adapting this to my layout and it works nicely. I only had a few issues (as far as margins go) since it's basically a table. So thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes margins need a little extra work: you can replace them by `padding` or `border-spacing` or another element inside each "cell" (and you can also play with margin on table or container of the table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/Y2ZsJ/

Just add this to your css:

```
.container { overflow: hidden; }
.container div { 
  padding-bottom: 9999px;
  margin-bottom: -9999px;
}
```

(from: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ under the heading: One True Layout Method)

Comment: OP stated that he can't use `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Still a useful technique (and link). I seldom use `overflow: hidden;` (because of its future consequences in a project) so I played with it for the last 10 minutes in jsfiddle :)