# Make div fill remaining space of parent

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I need some help with positioning divs. The HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="left">
            lorem lorem
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>right</p>
            <p class="bottom">bottom</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
.container {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 600px;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 570px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The width and height of the left div is dynamic.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Make the height of the right div equal to height of the left div.
2. Make the width of the right div fill the rest of the div with class `item`.
3. The paragraph with class `bottom` should be at the bottom of the right div.

Here is a simple image that represents my goal:
[image]

And a link to a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PCvy9/).

Comment: Are you looking for a purely CSS solution or would you accept JavaScript?

Comment: If it is not possible in pure CSS I would accept Javascript solution, but CSS would be better

Comment: This is possible in pure CSS with IE8+

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting the correct position and width of `.bottom` appears to be the biggest hurdle for a cross-browser, CSS solution.

### Options

**1. Floats**

As @joeellis demonstrated, the flexible widths can be achieved by floating only the left column, and applying `overflow:hidden` to the right column.

The position of `.bottom` cannot be achieved in any browser. There's no CSS solution for floated columns with equal, variable height. An absolutely positioned `.bottom` element must be inside the right column div, so that 100% width would give it the correct size. But since the right column won't necessarily be as tall as the left column, positioning `.bottom` with `bottom:0` won't necessarily place it at the bottom of the container.

**2. HTML tables and CSS tables**

The flexible widths can be achieved by giving the left cell a width of 1px and not specifying a width for the right cell. Both cells will grow to fit the content. Any extra space will be added to the right cell alone.

If `.bottom` is inside the right table cell, the position can't be achieved in Firefox. Relative position has no effect in a table cell in Firefox; absolute position and 100% width would not be relative to the right table cell.

If `.bottom` is treated as a separate table cell in the right column, the correct heights of the right and bottom table cells cannot be achieved in any browser other than Firefox. Table cells aren't flexible in height the same way they are in width (except in Firefox).

**3. CSS3 flexbox and CSS3 grids**

Flexbox and grids are the promising layout tools of the near future. But flexbox isn't supported by IE9 or earlier, and grids aren't supported by any browser other than IE10. Haven't tested if either can achieve this layout, but browser support may prevent them from being an option at present.

### Summary

- Floats don't offer a solution for any browser.
- HTML tables and [CSS tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html) don't offer a cross-browser solution.
- [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) doesn't offer a potential solution for [IE9 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) (and may or may not offer a solution to other browsers).
- [Grids](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-layout/) only offer a potential solution to [IE10](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) (and may or may not offer a solution there).

### Conclusion

There doesn't appear to be an adequate CSS solution at present, one that would work in enough relevant browsers, with the possible exception of flexbox (if support for IE9 and earlier isn't required).

### jQuery

Here's a couple modified demos that use jQuery to force the columns to have the same height. The CSS and jQuery for both demos is the same. The HTML only differs by how much content is in the left and right column. Both demos tested fine in all browsers. The same basic approach could be used for plain JavaScript.

- [Taller content on the left](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/sjvCZ/3/)
- [Taller content on the right](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/xK2sr/2/)

To keep things simple, I moved the internal padding for the left and right div to a child element (`.content`).

Comment: @user1292810: I added a simple jQuery solution, with a couple demos.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I must support IE7 and newer. Against, there is already jQuery included to that website, so I stay with jQuery solution.

Comment: Flexbox does work as expected except on IE9-. It still needs 3 different syntax due to the evolution of the spec but it works. Working bricks (with all prefix and syntax in a few well-named classes) can be found on http://knacss.com/builder/ (click on 'Classic' and then search for flex)

Answer (score 9):

Sibling elements of same height and staying on the same row can be achieved by **displaying them as `table-cell`** and parent as `display: table`.
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SgubR/2/ (which also display the *`overflow: hidden` along a floating element* technique for creating a column. The latter needs a clearfix)

Table-cell in CSS uses any HTML element you want (section, div, span, li, whatever), its semantics is unrelated to table, tr and td elements used for table layout (except that the visual result is the same, that's what we want).

- `display: table` is set on a parent
- `display: table-row` may be used on an element in-between but if it works without it, fine
- `display: table-cell` is set on each child
- a width is set on none, some or all these "cells". Browser will adapt both to content and widths set in order to calculate their widths (and total width of parent, obviously)
- `table-layout: fixed` will tell browsers to switch to the *other* table layout algorithm where they don't care about the quantity of content, only to widths set by CSS
- `vertical-align: top` will be needed in most cases (but you may set other values, great for complex layouts)
- margins aren't applied on "cells", only padding. Margins only apply on table itself. Though you still can separate "cells" with `border-collapse: separate` and/or `border-spacing: 4px 6px`

Compatibility: IE8+
Fallback for IE6/7 if needed is exactly the same as for inline-block

Longer explanations in previous answers: **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359407/sidebar-height-stretch-with-the-content-height-css/11359442#11359442)** and **[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019386/html-css-how-to-create-four-equal-size-tabs-that-fill-100-width/12019783#12019783)** with also the good old method of *faux-columns* (your design must be thought with this technique in mind)

Comment: Good way to make all children adjust well to parents size, the rest only talk about one.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an `oveflow` to the right column and don't float it.

```
.right {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will make `right` to fill the rest of the width.

Comment: Though that'll create a column along a floating element, that won't `make height of the right div equal to height of the left div` as requested by OP

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

http://jsfiddle.net/PCvy9/2/

The main key of what you're looking for lines in the:

```
 .right {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #C82927;
 }
```

This is due to something called the "block formatting context."  Great reasoning and tutorial as to why here: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

However, their heights are not completely linked;  in this example, your left side block's height would still need to be manually set (as it's a floated container)

Comment: That doesn't fill the height, though (there was a typo in the original JSFiddle; the `bottom` class wasn't applied: http://jsfiddle.net/PCvy9/3/

Comment: No, unless you set a heights on the those two elements, or a height on the wrapping container and add `min-height: 100%` to the two child containers, they won't fill out.  That's because the `lorem ipsum` container is floated.

Comment: +1 Clever solution for the flexible-width part of the problem, even if it doesn't address equal heights. Didn't have any luck with this in IE8 or earlier using IETester, but not sure if that's due to IETester.

Comment: @MattCoughlin IMO IETester is a piece of ... because it's unreliable. Is this bug real or due to the tool used for testing? Is my bugfix OK on IE or just on IETester? I've seen countless hours lost due to this tool. Better use VMs from http://modern.ie , these at least are reliable (lesser IEs are sufficiently unreliable by themselves not to add an extra layer...)

Comment: I went back and tested on Litmus (instead of IETester) and it's fine in IE7 and later.