# How make flexible blocks without flexbox for old IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, flexbox

There is a question about simple form, with input and button,
Цe need a block filled 100% of the available space inside the box in which there may be other elements, without their wraps.

[image]

This is easily done with the flexbox, but it does not support IE 8-9.
Please help me. thx, Eugene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **CSS** table layout should give you flexibility depending of content: http://jsfiddle.net/37rxjskx/

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    /* table-layout: fixed; */
    /* width: 100%; */
}

.col,
button {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    outline: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">input auto 100% of the free width space</div>
    <button type="submit">button<br> auto of the<br> inner content</button>
</div>
```

`table-layout: fixed` does the opposite: make browsers apply your constraints of width and ignore relative quantity of content.

Various previous answers I did on the same subject: [equal width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526275/137626), [same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322191/html-css-2-column-layout-both-columns-same-height-automatically/12322268#12322268), [fill remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853403/137626)